# How to Rerender a uiComponent (insertForm) after first render?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

I have created a uiForm and inserted another UI Form using `insertForm`. And It is rendered on `fieldset` open. But after the main form data update, I want to re-render the form. I am not able to re-render the form with updated data and content.